# how to recognise mandatory and optional fields in the xml

Tags: web-services

Our Business had given only WSDL which contains 200 elements and  we are not aware of mandatory and optional fields , Once i imported WSDL in to the soap tool ,i dont see mandatory and optional fields in the XML and there is no documentation or support to test this WSDL.

so how to we recognise what all mandatory and optional fields in the xml?

Answer (score 2):

You look inside the WSDL you received and search for elements that have attributes of `minOccurs="0"`.

If an element has `minOccurs="0"` it means that it can appear in the XML a minimum of zero times which in turn means it can be missing altogether. If it can be missing from the XML then it means it's an optional field.

The elements that have `minOccurs > 0` are mandatory elements.